# Missing cell policy of Apache POI Java

Tags: java, apache-poi

Can somebody please explain about the `Missing cell policy` of `Apache POI` ? What are exactly missing cells ? I didn't find the `Apache POI` docs [link](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/class-use/Row.MissingCellPolicy.html) to be self-explanatory on what exactly are missing cells.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Did you read the [Apache POI Excel Busy Developer's Guide](http://poi.apache.org/spreadsheet/quick-guide.html#Iterator)?

> In some cases, when iterating, you need full control over how missing or blank rows and cells are treated, and you need to ensure you visit every cell and not just those defined in the file. (The CellIterator will only return the cells defined in the file, which is largely those with values or stylings, but it depends on Excel).
>
> In cases such as these, you should fetch the first and last column information for a row, then call getCell(int, MissingCellPolicy) to fetch the cell. Use a MissingCellPolicy to control how blank or null cells are handled.

If you're iterating over columns in a row, some cells that are blank may not even exist, which may causing unsuspecting code to throw a `NullPointerException`.  A `MissingCellPolicy`, when passed to `getCell`, guides and simplifies code that tells Apache POI how to handle these kinds of cells.

- [CREATE_NULL_AS_BLANK](http://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/Row.html#CREATE_NULL_AS_BLANK) - If the `Cell` returned doesn't exist, instead of returning `null`, create a new `Cell` with a cell type of "blank".  This can help avoid `NullPointerException`s conveniently.
- [RETURN_BLANK_AS_NULL](http://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/Row.html#RETURN_BLANK_AS_NULL) - Even if the cell exists but has a cell type of "blank", return `null`.  This can allow you ignore blank cells that do exist easily.
- [RETURN_NULL_AND_BLANK](http://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/Row.html#RETURN_NULL_AND_BLANK) - Don't modify the existing structure; return `null` for cells that don't really exist and return the blank `Cell` if it exists but its cell type is blank.  This is the behavior of the [`getCell` overload that doesn't take a `MissingCellPolicy`](http://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/Row.html#getCell(int)).

Comment: I'm having a weird case here : System.out.println ( row.getCell(13, Row.CREATE_NULL_AS_BLANK).getStringCellValue()) , it is still printing null.

Comment: @Ashley `Row.CREATE_NULL_AS_BLANK` by definition creates a `Blank` cell not a `String` one, so you shouldn't be trying to get the String value!

Answer (score 1):

I'm using the code in java as below, it's working good for me :) hope it helps.

```
ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> cellArrayListHolder = new ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>();
FileInputStream excelFile = new FileInputStream(new File(fileName));

Workbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook(excelFile);
Sheet datatypeSheet = workbook.getSheetAt(0);
Iterator<Row> iterator = datatypeSheet.iterator();
while (iterator.hasNext())
{
    ArrayList<String> cellStoreArrayList = new ArrayList<String>();
    Row currentRow = iterator.next();
    Iterator<Cell> cellIterator = currentRow.iterator();
    int column_counting = 0;
    int patched_count = 0;
    while (cellIterator.hasNext() && column_counting < read_column_size) {
        column_counting ++;
        Cell currentCell = cellIterator.next();
        int missed_column = 1 - column_counting + currentCell.getColumnIndex() - patched_count;  
        for(int i=0; i<missed_column; i++){
            cellStoreArrayList.add("");
            patched_count++;
        }
        switch (currentCell.getCellType()){
        case Cell.CELL_TYPE_STRING:
            cellStoreArrayList.add(String.valueOf(currentCell).trim());
            break;
        case Cell.CELL_TYPE_NUMERIC:
            if (DateUtil.isCellDateFormatted(currentCell)) {
                DateFormat db_df = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss yyyy");
                cellStoreArrayList.add(db_df.format(currentCell.getDateCellValue()));
            } else {
                cellStoreArrayList.add(String.valueOf(currentCell.getNumericCellValue()));
            }
            break;
        case Cell.CELL_TYPE_BOOLEAN:
            cellStoreArrayList.add(String.valueOf(currentCell.getBooleanCellValue()));
            break;
        default:
            cellStoreArrayList.add("");
            break;
        }
    }
    cellArrayListHolder.add(cellStoreArrayList);
}
```