# Apache Poi adding missing cell policy in XssfReader and SheetContentsHandler

Tags: java, excel, apache, apache-poi

Consider the following Excel table

```
Id         Reference Id    Name
20059136                    Gj
20012323                    Am
```

How to handle missing cells in `Event model`  `XSSFReader`, While reading data here the column `Reference Id` is skipped and one left shift happens, hence all the values from `Name` column are appended over to `Reference Id` in the read output.

How to find missing cells or empty/blank cells using `Apache POI` 'XssfReader' and 'SheetContentsHandler'.

1. How to find the `missing cells` dynamically in case of a very large set of file reads?
2. As well as how to add `MissingCellPolicy` in the case of `Event Model'?

references

1. https://stackoverflow.com/a/36776914/4522875
2. https://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/poi/trunk/src/examples/src/org/apache/poi/xssf/eventusermodel/XLSX2CSV.java

thanks.

Comment: Have a read of [XLSX2CSV in the Apache POI examples package](https://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/poi/trunk/src/examples/src/org/apache/poi/xssf/eventusermodel/XLSX2CSV.java) and search for `Did we miss any cells?` - all the missing cell logic you need is in there!

Comment: In my case few cell references are missing, I mean `B2` in the case of above given Excel from the read output. When I print the row indexes I get the following output with `B2` missing `{ A2 C2 D2 }` in this sequence

Comment: As I already said, implement your own logic to spot missed cells much as `// Did we miss any cells?` has

Answer (score 0):

Hope this helps,

```
    @Override
    public void cell(String cellReference, String formattedValue, XSSFComment comment) {
        if (currentRow == this.headerRow) {
            // populate headers 
            populateHeaders(cellReference, formattedValue));
        } else if(currentRow > this.headerRow){
            // populate values based on position referencing particular header
            final String header = headers.get(cellReference.replaceAll(String.valueOf(currentRow + 1), "") + this.headerRow);
            values.put(header, formattedValue);
        }
    }
```

The hack is getting`currentRow` using the following method,

```
    @Override
    public void startRow(int rowNum) {
        currentRow = rowNum;
        values = new LinkedHashMap<>();
    }
```

and populating extracted data using header positions,

```
        // populate values based on position referencing particular header
        final String header = headers.get(cellReference.replaceAll(String.valueOf(currentRow + 1), "") + this.headerRow);
```

Missing cells could be sanitized later with blank, empty or custom values based on own logics, Thanks.