# Apache POI MissingCellPolicy not working for excel read and write operations

Tags: java, excel, apache, apache-poi

I am trying to use Apache POI for excel read and write actions in Java. When I am trying to pass cells which don't any data in excel it is expected to return blank but- Java Null pointer exception is throwing instead.However, when I am passing cells which have some data both methods getCelldata and setCelldata are working perfectly.
Here is the code snippet

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFCell;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFRow;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFSheet;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Row;

    public class ExcelUtils {
                private static XSSFSheet ExcelWSheet;
                private static XSSFWorkbook ExcelWBook;
                private static XSSFCell xCell;
                private static XSSFRow xRow;

            //This method is to set the File path and to open the Excel file, Pass Excel Path and Sheetname as Arguments to this method

            public static void setExcelFile(String Path,String SheetName) throws Exception {
                try {

                    // Access the required test data sheet
                    FileInputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream(new File(Path));         
                    ExcelWBook = new XSSFWorkbook(inputStream);
                    ExcelWSheet = ExcelWBook.getSheet(SheetName);
                    } catch (Exception e){
                        throw (e);
                    }
            }

            //This method is to read the test data from the Excel cell, in this we are passing parameters as Row num and Col num

            public static String getCellData(int RowNum, int ColNum) throws Exception{
                try{
                    xCell = ExcelWSheet.getRow(RowNum).getCell(ColNum, Row.MissingCellPolicy.CREATE_NULL_AS_BLANK);
                    String CellData = xCell.getStringCellValue();
                    return CellData;
                    }catch (Exception e){
                        throw(e);
                    }
            }

            //This method is to write in the Excel cell, Row num and Col num are the parameters

            public static void setCellData(String Result,  int RowNum, int ColNum) throws Exception {

                try{
                    xRow  = ExcelWSheet.getRow(RowNum);
                    xCell = xRow.getCell(ColNum, Row.MissingCellPolicy.RETURN_BLANK_AS_NULL);
                    if (xCell == null) {
                        xCell = xRow.createCell(ColNum);
                        xCell.setCellValue(Result);
                        } else {
                            xCell.setCellValue(Result);
                        }
          // Constant variables Test Data path and Test Data file name

                        FileOutputStream fileOut = new FileOutputStream(Constants.Path_TestData);
                        ExcelWBook.write(fileOut);
                        fileOut.flush();
                        fileOut.close();
                        }catch(Exception e){
                            throw (e);
                    }
                }
    }
```

Error throwing at line but expected xCell should have blank value since i have provided MissingCellPolicy

```
xCell = ExcelWSheet.getRow(RowNum).getCell(ColNum, Row.MissingCellPolicy.CREATE_NULL_AS_BLANK);
```

And

```
xCell = xRow.getCell(ColNum, Row.MissingCellPolicy.RETURN_BLANK_AS_NULL);
```

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably you are passing an entirely empty row that is why your getRow() method is failing and giving you a NullPointerException.

While you're iterating over columns in a row, some cells that are blank may not even exist, which may causing unsuspecting code to throw a NullPointerException. A MissingCellPolicy, is only applied to a cell. So you can't keep the entire row empty

**CREATE_NULL_AS_BLANK** - If the Cell returned doesn't exist, instead of returning null, create a new Cell with a cell type of "blank". This can help avoid NullPointerExceptions conveniently.

**RETURN_BLANK_AS_NULL** - Even if the cell exists but has a cell type of "blank", return null. This can allow you ignore blank cells that do exist easily.

**RETURN_NULL_AND_BLANK** - Don't modify the existing structure; return null for cells that don't really exist and return the blank Cell if it exists but its cell type is blank. This is the behavior of the getCell overload that doesn't take a MissingCellPolicy.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36776745/missing-cell-policy-of-apache-poi-java    --- a similar kind of issue that helped me.

Comment: Yeah! that's the issue I am passing entirely empty row. Thanks. BTW how to know if I am passing entirely empty row before using getCell method

Comment: Iterator<Row> rowIterator = sheet.rowIterator();       

while (rowIterator.hasNext()) {           

Row row =rowIterator.next();    

// Check if the row is empty or null here

      // Now let's iterate over the columns of the current row       

     Iterator<Cell> cellIterator = row.cellIterator();

You can try something like this